# Rendering multiple leaflet maps in Angular

Tags: angular, leaflet

I am trying to render multiple leaflet maps on the same page using angular. ngFor is used to render maps dynamically. Number of maps depend on data received from a REST service.

**map.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let m of mapIds">
    <div class="map" [id]="m"></div>
</div>
```

**map.component.ts**

[*Version 1*] - data is not populated in this.mapIds

```
ngOnInit() {
    PopulateData();

    // do other stuff
}

PopulateData() {            

    // Invoke Web service
    this.cService.getMapData(cInput).subscribe(
        (res: getMapData[]) =>
        {
            // form a list of mapIds
            this.mapIds = mapIds
        }
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Initialize leaflet maps
    this.mapIds.forEach( x => {         // <--- this.mapIds is null
        this.maps[x] = L.map(x, {       
            attributionControl: false,
            minZoom: 3,
            maxZoom: 7,
            zoomControl: false
        });

        // rest of map initialization 
    })
}
```

[*Version 2*] gives the following error

> Error: Map container not found.

```
ngOnInit() {
    PopulateData();

    // do other stuff

    InitMaps();
}

PopulateData() {            

    // Invoke Web service
    this.cService.getMapData(cInput).subscribe(
        (res: getMapData[]) =>
        {
            // form a list of mapIds
            this.mapIds = mapIds
        }
}

InitMaps() {
    // Initialize leaflet maps
    this.mapIds.forEach( x => {
        this.maps[x] = L.map(x, {        // <-- Error thrown here
            attributionControl: false,
            minZoom: 3,
            maxZoom: 7,
            zoomControl: false
        });

        // rest of map initialization 
    })
}
```

Is there a way to wait until `this.mapIds` is populated in *Version 1* ? Or any other suggestions?

Comment: What is "L" in your code ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve what you are trying to do if you move your `ngAfterViewInit()` code into `populateData()`

```
populateData() {            
    // Invoke Web service
    this.cService.getMapData(cInput).subscribe(
        (res: getMapData[]) =>
        {
            res.forEach( x => {
                this.maps[x] = L.map(x, {       
                    attributionControl: false,
                    minZoom: 3,
                    maxZoom: 7,
                    zoomControl: false
                });                        
        }
}
```

The reason why you are getting `this.mapIds is null` is because at the time `ngAfterViewInit()` executes, `PopulateData()` hasn't been completed yet.

Comment: This does not work - still get "Map container not found" error. The sequence should be as follows : Invoke Webservice and populate "mapIds" -> this will trigger angular to form appropriate div tags -> initialize leaflet using L.map(...)